# Java EE: Interceptor and Singleton, how to intercept before Singleton con check

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In Java EE the @Singleton Annotation does make access to the Singleton thread-safe by synchronizing access to it.

Now, I want to use an Interceptor for the class to measure how long calls to the Singleton take.

My Problem is, the Interceptor gets called after a Thread is allowed to use the Singleton. This way I only get how long a Method is running, but not how long the caller had to wait to get access to the singleton.

I basically want to do:

```
Caller
---Interceptor
------Singleton
```

But with just using @Singleton and @Interceptor I get:

```
Caller
---Singleton
------Interceptor
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: not with the jee interceptor for sure.

Comment: but could be useful to find a solution to this. a nice one

Comment: in wildfly (jboss AS) there are container interceptors, those might work. "The container interceptors configured for a EJB are guaranteed to be run before the WildFly provided security interceptors, transaction management interceptors and other such interceptors thus allowing the user application specific container interceptors to setup any relevant context data before the invocation proceeds." https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Container+interceptors

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict access to the singleton on your own using @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html

Restrict necessary access methods by hand and include the pointcut code there.